# Get data from wp_editor()

Tags: wp-insert-post, wp-editor

I can use `wp_editor()` function for add custom post use `wp_insert_post()` function (with post_content parameter) in my plugin.

I need to can be saved data from `wp_editor()` function.

How can i get output ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: It should just be in `$_POST` with whatever name you gave the textarea it's attached to.

Comment: @JacobPeattie friend, i tried this way but i can't get data from wp_editor

Comment: Can you provide bit more Info like how you have set up the wp_editor and how are you trying to access the content?

Answer (score 3):

```
 $content = '';
 $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
 wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );


/** If you want to get data wp_editor value from POST **/


 print_r($_POST['mycustomeditor']);
```